# AngularJS factory return no data first time, but after called interval method it does

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope

Im trying to make a AngularJS factory that provides my app with a list of businesses. But i cant seem to get the variable the first time this is run. But after interval is run, i get the variable.

I get this on the first run on the controller in the page:

> angular.js:12783 Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'businessList' must return a value from $get factory method

But I think my solution is faulty, any how? Can anyone point me in the right direction here? For example is using rootScope here a good idea?

What I want is a globally accessible list of businesses in my app, that is collected on start of visit, and updates itself with a timer. So i dont have to all the time call for induvidial requests from the laravel backend, when i can just find it in that list.. is my idea.

Factory:

```
myApp.factory('businessList', ['$interval', '$http', '$rootScope',
    function($interval, $http, $rootScope) {
      function bedriftliste() {
        $http.get('get/allebedrifter')
            .then(function(result) {
                bedrifter = result.data;
                $rootScope.bedrifter = bedrifter;
            });
        return $rootScope.bedrifter;
    }
    var bedrifter = bedriftliste();
    // start periodic checking
    $interval(bedriftliste, 5000);
    return bedrifter;
}
]);
```

Controller

```
myApp.controller('bsC', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'businessList', 
                    function($rootScope, $scope, businessList) {
    $scope.allebedrifter = businessList;
}]);`
```

Comment: The reason why it throws error at first time, because the $rootScope.bedrifter was undefined when the factory was loaded the first time. It only has values after the $http response is resolved.

Comment: Yes, but this doesnt work: $rootScope.bedrifter = bedriftliste();

Comment: of course that doesn't work. Just before I provide any answer, can I please know if you have any other working services with $http? if yes, why do you write this service this way? Just to make sure you know the $http and promises.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just doing a http.get if object was null.

```
        if (!$rootScope.allebedrifter) { 
        $http.get('get/bedrift/' + $scope.tslug)
            .then(function(result) {
                bedriften = result.data;
                $scope.bedriften = bedriften;
       });
```

Seems to work fine like this

Answer (score 0):

Although I am late in pointing out but that doesn't seem to be a proper solution to this problem. You need to make these changes in factory:

```
myApp.factory('businessList', ['$interval', '$http', '$rootScope',
function($interval, $http, $rootScope) {
  function bedriftliste() {
    return $http.get('get/allebedrifter');
}
```

}
]);

and in the controller you'll do something like this:

```
myApp.controller('bsC', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'businessList', function($rootScope, $scope, businessList) {
                    function TestFunction(){
     businessList.bedriftliste().then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.allebedrifter = response.data;
//it will invoke 5 seconds after you receive the response from your factory method, I didn't test it but it will solve your problem
        $interval(TestFunction, 5000);
    }, function errorCallback(response) { 
    });
}
```

}]);